# DelimitedLineTokenizer tab character

Tags: java, tabs

How can I fix this problem:

```
<bean id=" productLineTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
        <property name="delimiter" value="\t"/>
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
String [\t] with length 2 cannot be converted to char type
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a constant

```
<property name="delimiter">
    <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB"/>
</property>
```